# Monitor FOR loop progress in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres loop as follows, which I am running from the command line via psql:

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN 
   FOR i IN 1..20000
   -- update some rows
   LOOP
END LOOP;
END; 
$do$;
```

Is there any way to access the value of the counter `i` to track the progress of the loop? I've looked in the pgAdmin dashboard with no success.

Comment: Create some service table. Update the value relative to this procedure in it. Set your client to select this data periodically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding raise notice. It will keep printing value of i -- so that you will always have idea about loop progress.

```
    DO
    $do$
    BEGIN 
    FOR i IN 1..20000
    -- update some rows
    raise notice 'Current Progress Value i:%',i;
     LOOP
    END LOOP;
    END;
```

Or more better way.

1. Create a sql file  : vi loop.sql  -- add your loop into this file with raise notice.
2. Run as a job: psql -U username -d database_name -a -f loop.sql &>progress_log
3. Keep monitoring latest id : tail progress_log

*Note: One more tip- I think you need to initialize i - need to include a declare section. Like below:(sample)*

```
    DO
    $do$
    DECLARE
    i int8;
    BEGIN
    -----your code--
    END;
```

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly. What do you mean about the declare section, though? It works fine without any declare, and the examples in the documentation don't mention it.

Comment: @amball - good if it's working for your without declaration. I'm modifying my answer - so that you can see how you can declare i . It's pgsql block syntax.